# Is this an acceptable MVVM Model with IEditableObject implementation?

Tags: design-patterns, vb.net, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to follow MVVM pattern in a VB.net WPF application, and I would like to implement `IEditableObject`.

Is this code acceptable for an MVVM application? In particular is it okay to have the `IEditableObject` implemented here on the Model rather than the ViewModel?

```
Public Class Component : Implements IEditableObject
    Property Name As String
    Property Part_Number As String
    Property Position_Count As Integer
    Property Stage as Integer
    Private _stored_properties As Hashtable = Nothing

    ReadOnly Property Full_Name As String
        Get
            Return Name + " " + Stage.ToString()
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub BeginEdit() Implements IEditableObject.BeginEdit
        Dim properties = Me.GetType.GetProperties
        _stored_properties = New Hashtable(properties.Length - 1)
        For Each prop In properties
            If prop.GetSetMethod IsNot Nothing Then _stored_properties.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(Me, Nothing))
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub EndEdit() Implements IEditableObject.EndEdit
        _stored_properties = Nothing
    End Sub

    Public Sub CancelEdit() Implements IEditableObject.CancelEdit
        If _stored_properties Is Nothing Then Return
        Dim properties = Me.GetType.GetProperties
        For Each prop In properties
            If prop.GetSetMethod IsNot Nothing Then prop.SetValue(Me, _stored_properties(prop.Name))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do you want a code review, or just an answer to your question? If you just want an answer it might be better to ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Sorry quite inexperienced on this part of SE, I take it both isn't an acceptable answer? I can edit it to just be code review if required?

Comment: No, now that you've clarified what you are looking for it's fine.